# C# ListView - Searching for exact time value (HH:mm:ss) or closest value

Tags: c#, list, listview, arraylist, listviewitem

I am looking for a way to search through a listview for either an exact value or the closest value to it in the list.

The values are all time values ("HH:mm:ss"). I dont have much of the code written yet but I'll post what I have so far.

The following method references a ListView called lstData, which holds the time values. The index is passed to the method selecting a certain time.
What I want to do is take the value at this location in lstData and find the same value or the closest value in another ListView called lstReport. lst Report doesn't necessarily have the same time values but a lot of similiar ones and in the same format, therefore I want the closest value in lstReport to be selected.

```
private void SelectTime(int val)
    {
        try
        {
            CurrentIndex = val;
            lstData.Items[CurrentIndex].Selected = true;
            lstData.EnsureVisible(CurrentIndex);

            String text = lstData.Items[CurrentIndex].Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Time Selected: " + text);


            // This is where I want to search lstReport for the closest time value 
            // to lstData.Items[CurrentIndex] value

            this.Refresh();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

I apologise if I have not explained this very well at all, if this is the case please leave a comment and I will try to make it clearer. Thanks

**EDIT**

```
// get the selected item from lstData
            String text = lstData.Items[CurrentIndex].Text;

            // parse the value
            long SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(text).Ticks;
            //  extract the listview items into a list of strings
            List<string> list = lstData.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.Text).ToList();
            //By converting the values to Long, we can get the closest value using Math.Abs.
            string closest = list.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(x).Ticks - SelectedDate) < Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(y).Ticks - SelectedDate) ? x : y);
```

Comment: for each items of the second list, substract the date item, get the totalSeconds of the timeSpan, do Math.Abs() and keep the lowest result may do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ to get the closest value by ordering the absolute difference of the time. Let´s say you have the two lists `lstReport` and `lstData` of type `DateTime`. Then do it like

```
private void SelectTime(int val)
{
    try
    {
        CurrentIndex = val;
        lstData.Items[CurrentIndex].Selected = true;
        lstData.EnsureVisible(CurrentIndex);

        String text = lstData.Items[CurrentIndex].Text;
        MessageBox.Show("Time Selected: " + text);

        //Get the closest DateTime to the Current item of lstData
        DateTime MinimumDifferenceItem = lstReport.Items.Cast<DateTime>().OrderBy(Dt => Math.Abs((Dt - (DateTime)lstData.Items[CurrentIndex]).Milliseconds)).First();

        this.Refresh();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Don´t forget to add

```
using System.Linq;
```

to your file.

**EDIT:**

If your Lists only containing Strings, you can modify the query by adding a `Convert.ToDateTime` like

```
String MinimumDifferenceItem = lstReport.Items.Cast<string>().OrderBy(Ts => Math.Abs((Convert.ToDateTime(Ts) - Convert.ToDateTime(lstData.Items[CurrentIndex])).Milliseconds)).First();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am getting the error: ListView does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy'

Comment: Sorry, small mistake: Use lstReport.Items.OrderBy(...);

Comment: No problem, for some reason it is still not liking the OrderBy and throwing the same error

Comment: I´ve added a Cast<Type>() to the quer. Now it should work wihout problems!

Comment: Thank you very much, will I need to cast the lstData.Items[CurrentIndex] also? It says Operator '-' cannot be applied to type DateTime and ListViewItem

Comment: Yes, just cast it like (DateTime)lstData.Items[CurrentIndex] ... I´ve edited this also.

Comment: In this cast I am getting the error 'unable to cast object of type ListViewItem to type String

Comment: Hi, the code is unchanged from what you have posted. The DateTime code - (DateTime)lstData.Items[CurrentIndex]) has the following error: Cannot convert from ListViewItem to System.DateTime. The string code in your Edit has the casting ListViewItem to type String error. I added in your examples to my code without editing them.

Comment: I think you don´t have DateTimes in your ListView. Try to use the second edited query of my answer! - If this is not working: Show the code you are filling your ListView!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TimeSpan` in the listview instead of `string`. Otherwise you'll have to do an unnecessary conversion.

After getting the Time from the first list view, loop through the second list view and calculate the difference between the two, keep track of the index in the second list and the difference in separate variables. When you find a time in the second list that is closer, update the index and difference variables.

When you are done you should have the time from the second list that is closest to the one from the first list. List view should automatically call `ToString()` on the TimeSpan so it should display fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Example List containing the time values
        List<string> dates = new List<string>();
        dates.Add("00:00:01");
        dates.Add("00:00:02");
        dates.Add("00:00:03");
        dates.Add("00:00:09");
        dates.Add("00:00:05");
        dates.Add("00:00:07");

        //The time value selected in the listview
        long SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse("00:00:04").Ticks;

        //By converting the values to Long, we can get the closest value using Math.Abs.
        string closest = dates.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(x).Ticks - SelectedDate) < Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(y).Ticks - SelectedDate) ? x : y);
```

UPDATE MATCHING YOUR REQUEST:

You mentioned you have two listview lstData and lstReport. You select a value from lstData and want to output the closest value contained in lstReport.
Just try the following steps:

1. store the selected value in a string variable 
   `String text = lstData.Items[CurrentIndex].Text;`
2. Cast it to a Type of Long: 
   `long selectedvalue = DateTime.Parse(text).Ticks;`
3. Cast the items in lsReport to a list of strings: 
   `List<string> valuelist = lstReport.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Select(item => item.Text) .ToList();`
4. compare the valuelist to the selectedvalue to get the closest: 
   `string closest = valuelist.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(x).Ticks - selectedvalue) < Math.Abs(DateTime.Parse(y).Ticks - selectedvalue) ? x : y);`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am getting the error: ListView does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate'

Comment: All you have to do is extract the listviewitems into a list of strings: `List<string> list = lstData.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>()
                                 .Select(item => item.Text)
                                 .ToList();`

Comment: Hi I have tried this and it is always showing the closest time as being exactly the same as the selected time.

Comment: Thats right yes, however, the closest match and the value are both the same, and the closes value is a value which is not in lstReport.

Comment: Can you check the edit I have put on the bottom of the original post, I may still be coding it wrong, thanks Innat3.

Comment: the problem is you are comparing the selected value extracted from lstData to the values on lstData themselves! I have updated my answer to match your needs

Comment: I thought I must have been doing that! Now when I run the code it is saying that string closest is not recognised as a valid datetime.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, if you want to cast the string "closest" back to a DateTime just do a conversion `DateTime closestDate = DateTime.Parse(closest);` Otherwise, could you tell me what value is currently stored that is not recognised as valid? try placing a breakpoint and hovering over the stored value

Comment: After selectedvalue = DateTime.Parse(text).Ticks; the values are - text "04:22:07", selectedvalue 636076957270000000

Comment: Okay so the .Ticks converts the datetime value to a long integer in an unit measure of ticks. Now if you want to convert it back to a time format do the following: `TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromTicks(selectedvalue); string time = ts.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");` Assuming that 'selectedvalue' holds 636076957270000000, 'time' should output 04:22:07

Comment: Hi, I have just realise the string not recognised as a valid datetime error is at DateTime.Parse(x) and DateTime.Parse(y)

Comment: check the values stored inside the valuelist List at the exact moment that call is made. are they in hh:mm:ss format?

Comment: No the values are not in that format. They start off at 0 and the value increases for each list item